# json.net deserialize datetime in object

Tags: datetime, json.net, deserialization

I have a problem with deserialization of datetime. In JSON it comes in this *format 2016-10-04T15:20:00* but after deserialialization it changes to the AM/PM time format and I need to preserve the 24 hour format. Is there any way how specify the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deserialize to a date, the format is not stored inside the date object.  Instead, the formatting happens on output.  The default format for your locale is probably using 12-hour time.  If you want a different format, you can pass a format string to the `ToString` method:

```
string json = @"{ ""date"": ""2016-10-04T15:20:00"" }";

Foo foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);

Console.WriteLine(foo.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ibLCbG